# Create query using MongoDB commands

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is ***really important*** to me.
In the following, I should manipulate data using
MongoDB Aggregate pipeline and `$lookup`. I am not allowed to use MongoCompass for this section.
There is a Mongo database called Accessories with the following collections:

1. Products – all columns
2. ProductStock – product_id, product_name, warehouse_id,warehouse_name, location_id,    address, country_name,
   region_name,quantity
3. ProductSold – product_id, total qty sold

***products(product details):***

```
[
    {"Product_ID":1,"Product_Name":"G.Skill Ripjaws V Series","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3000,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:15Module:8x8GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":450,"List_Price":640,"Category_ID":5},
    {"Product_ID":2,"Product_Name":"Intel Xeon E5-2697 V4","Description":"Speed:2.3GHz,Cores:18,TDP:145W","Standard_Cost":2144,"List_Price":2554,"Category_ID":1},
    {"Product_ID":3,"Product_Name":"Corsair CB-9060011-WW","Description":"Chipset:GeForce GTX 1080 Ti,Memory:11GBCore Clock:1.57GHz","Standard_Cost":573,"List_Price":799,"Category_ID":2},
    {"Product_ID":4,"Product_Name":"AMD 100-505989","Description":"Chipset:FirePro W9100,Memory:32GBCore Clock:930MHz","Standard_Cost":2128,"List_Price":2699,"Category_ID":2},
    {"Product_ID":5,"Product_Name":"PNY VCQK6000-PB","Description":"Chipset:Quadro K6000,Memory:12GBCore Clock:902MHz","Standard_Cost":1740,"List_Price":2290,"Category_ID":2},
    {"Product_ID":6,"Product_Name":"Zotac ZT-P10810A-10P","Description":"Chipset:GeForce GTX 1080 Ti,Memory:11GBCore Clock:1.48GHz","Standard_Cost":702,"List_Price":849,"Category_ID":2},
    {"Product_ID":7,"Product_Name":"G.Skill Ripjaws V Series","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3200,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:15Module:8x8GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":602,"List_Price":680,"Category_ID":5},
    {"Product_ID":8,"Product_Name":"Intel Xeon E5-1650 V4","Description":"Speed:3.6GHz,Cores:6,TDP:140W","Standard_Cost":535,"List_Price":601,"Category_ID":1},
    {"Product_ID":9,"Product_Name":"Intel Xeon E5-2640 V4","Description":"Speed:2.4GHz,Cores:10,TDP:90W","Standard_Cost":738,"List_Price":899,"Category_ID":1},
    {"Product_ID":10,"Product_Name":"Crucial","Description":"Speed:DDR4-2133,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:15Module:2x16GBSize:32GB","Standard_Cost":580,"List_Price":811,"Category_ID":5},
    {"Product_ID":11,"Product_Name":"PNY VCQP5000-PB","Description":"Chipset:Quadro P5000,Memory:16GBCore Clock:1.61GHz","Standard_Cost":1602,"List_Price":2015,"Category_ID":2},
    {"Product_ID":12,"Product_Name":"Gigabyte GV-N108TAORUSX W-11GD","Description":"Chipset:GeForce GTX 1080 Ti,Memory:11GBCore Clock:1.63GHz","Standard_Cost":596,"List_Price":824,"Category_ID":2},
    {"Product_ID":13,"Product_Name":"G.Skill Ripjaws V Series","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3333,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:16Module:4x16GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":618,"List_Price":704,"Category_ID":5},
    {"Product_ID":14,"Product_Name":"G.Skill Ripjaws V Series","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3333,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:16Module:4x16GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":633,"List_Price":704,"Category_ID":5},
    {"Product_ID":15,"Product_Name":"G.Skill Trident Z","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3466,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:16Module:4x16GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":601,"List_Price":725,"Category_ID":5},
    {"Product_ID":16,"Product_Name":"Intel Core i7-6900K","Description":"Speed:3.2GHz,Cores:8,TDP:140W","Standard_Cost":792,"List_Price":889,"Category_ID":1},
    {"Product_ID":17,"Product_Name":"Corsair Vengeance LPX","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3333,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:15Module:4x16GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":595,"List_Price":699,"Category_ID":5},
]
```

***productSold(product sold):***

```
[
    {"Product_ID":1,"TotalQuantity":457},
    {"Product_ID":2,"TotalQuantity":229},
    {"Product_ID":3,"TotalQuantity":147},
    {"Product_ID":4,"TotalQuantity":441},
    {"Product_ID":5,"TotalQuantity":109},
    {"Product_ID":6,"TotalQuantity":245},
]
```

***productStock(stock in inventory):***

```
[
    {"Product_ID":3,"Product_Name":"Corsair CB-9060011-WW","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":106},
    {"Product_ID":4,"Product_Name":"AMD 100-505989","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":106},
    {"Product_ID":5,"Product_Name":"PNY VCQK6000-PB","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":106},
    {"Product_ID":6,"Product_Name":"Zotac ZT-P10810A-10P","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":107},
    {"Product_ID":11,"Product_Name":"PNY VCQP5000-PB","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":108},
    {"Product_ID":12,"Product_Name":"Gigabyte GV-N108TAORUSX W-11GD","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":108},
    {"Product_ID":80,"Product_Name":"Intel Xeon E5-1650 V3","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":125},}
]
```

Queries:
Use MongoDB commands to demonstrate the following:

1. Query 1 – Implement a query to find out those products which have never been sold before
2. Query 2 – For those products from Query 1, implement a query to find their total stock available arranged in descending order. What insight do you discover from the results of the query?

The first query that works:

```
db.Products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ProductSold",
      localField: "Product_ID",
      foreignField: "Product_ID",
      as: "sold"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      sold: { $size: 0 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Product_ID: 1,
      Product_Name: 1,
      Description: 1,
      Standard_Cost: 1,
      List_Price: 1,
      Category_ID: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "count"
  }
]);
```

Query 2:

```
db.Products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ProductSold",
      localField: "Product_ID",
      foreignField: "Product_ID",
      as: "sold"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      sold: { $size: 0 }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ProductStock",
      localField: "Product_ID",
      foreignField: "Product_ID",
      as: "stockData"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$stockData",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Product_ID",
      Product_Name: { $first: "$Product_Name" },
      Description: { $first: "$Description" },
      Standard_Cost: { $first: "$Standard_Cost" },
      List_Price: { $first: "$List_Price" },
      Category_ID: { $first: "$Category_ID" },
      Total_Stock: { $sum: "$stockData.quantity" }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      Total_Stock: -1 // Sort in descending order of Total_Stock
    }
  }
]);
```

There are supposed to be 32 outputs for both queries.

But it is wrong, please help correct the second query. Thank you.

Edit:

[image]

The output should be something like this but unfortunately not all 32 products were shown.

[image]

The total stock derives from the sum of the quantity of products for all warehouses in all countries.

Comment: *I am NOT allowed to use MongoCampass for this section.* But you can use online compiler such as [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/), to work & test your query

Comment: @yongshun is it possible to combine the total quantity for each product for all countries together as 1 total quantity, if not the output will be very complicated, .eg product 22 have 222 stock quantity(referring to stock across globally)

Comment: *is it possible to combine the total quantity for each product for all countries together as 1 total quantity*. Group by `id: null` and $sum for `Total_Stock`? I don't get it for your statement *product 22 have 222 stock quantity(referring to stock across globally)*, would be great if you can further elaborate and provide expected output.

Comment: @yongshun please check the updated one

Comment: Sorry for late reply. *unfortunately not all 32 products were shown*, from your dataset, you didn't provide the complete dataset, so we can't know which 32 products or actual total number of records will be filtered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254724/discussion-between-mobly-elliot-and-yong-shun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ProductStock` collection, there is no `quantity` field, that is why you will get 0 for the `Total_Stock` field.

```
Total_Stock: { $sum: "$stockData.quantity" }
```

I believe that you probably mean the `Total_Quantity` field.

```
Total_Stock: { $sum: "$stockData.Total_Quantity" }
```

Meanwhile, would say that the `$unwind` and `$group` stages are unnecessary and will slow down the query performance to calculate the `Total_Stock`. The result from both stages can be achieved with the `$set` stage.

```
{
  $set: {
    Total_Stock: {
      $sum: "$stockData.Total_Quantity"
    }
  }
}
```

The complete query for the 2nd query:

```
db.Products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ProductSold",
      localField: "Product_ID",
      foreignField: "Product_ID",
      as: "sold"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      sold: {
        $size: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ProductStock",
      localField: "Product_ID",
      foreignField: "Product_ID",
      as: "stockData"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      Total_Stock: {
        $sum: "$stockData.Total_Quantity"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      Total_Stock: -1// Sort in descending order of Total_Stock
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ePTeiNqsskv)